# Column association in cakephp

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm working on a project and want to create a form in cakephp.

I have a Table name "Plan". And Table "Plan" Have some column like.

Colum 1 : Plan Name1         , Plan Name2
Colum 2 : Plan Description1  , Plan Description2
Colum 3 : Plan Amount1       , Plan Amount2

And in my form (Cakephp View File) I have tree options..
Plan 
   Plan Description
       Plan Amount.

And I want when I select Plan Name1 from Drop Down.
 Plan Description1 and Plan Amount1 Auto Select in the Related Field.

I search on google and cakephp but didn't find solution for that.

Comment: It is too general question. It will be tons of methods to achieve that. If you want to change other dropdowns when you change Plan you need to use Javascript and write code to do following: "on change Plan dropdown set Plan Description = value and Plan Amount = value". Now your question require us to completely write code for you. It isn't what stackoverflow is designed for. Start to write code and return with specific questions.

Comment: I can do that with JavaScript. But I'm unable to write the script for cakephp. Please ignore it if it's not a way to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Search for [JsHelper request method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::request)